# qt command line application compilation

Tags: c++, macos, qt, command, line

trying to compile this simple qt application

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   QPushButton hello("Hello world!");
   hello.resize(100, 30);

   hello.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

trying to compile with

```
 g++ -I /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Headers -o example main.cpp -framework QtGui -framework QtCore
```

getting error

```
 main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'QApplication' file not found
 #include <QApplication>
     ^
 1 error generated.
```

have checked existence of header file and that it is contained in dir

```
 :Headers ali$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/
 $ ls
 Headers        QtGui       QtGui.prl   Resources   Versions
```

any suggestions as to where im going wrong

Comment: I'm not seeing where "/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Headers" is being put in your include search path. Where is that happening?

Comment: sorry very new to c++ and compelling code by hand got both the code and the compile command of the internet they edited it to fit with the version of qt I have installed

Comment: Does the "Headers" directory contain QApplication.h?

Comment: no it dose not  QApplication.h

Comment: You'll need to figure out where that is then. Cause that's where you're telling your compiler it's at.

Comment: thanks man will track down that file

Comment: Usually it's in the QtWidgets directory. If that's the case you can just add that to your compiler's include statement.

Comment: found it under  cd /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Headers. thanks so much

Comment: Yup, I'll add this as an answer if you feel like accepting that would probably make sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The path that you are telling your compiler to look for "QApplication.h" doesn't contain "QApplication.h":

> -I /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Headers

In a typical install, "QApplication.h" would be in the "QtWidgets", not "QtGui", directory. So you'll probably want to include that directory instead.

Comment: @Downvoter any particular reason for the down vote? No need to respond if it's just the mandatory C++ down vote.